# Url Helpers in ActiveModelSerializer 0.10.0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

I know this version is still not officially released but I was checking out rc3 today and I noticed that I can no longer use Rails url helpers inside my serializers. In version 0.8.x, I could do the following:

```
class BrandSerializer < BaseSerializer
  attributes :id, :name, :slug, :state
  attributes :_links

  def _links
    {
      self: api_v1_company_brand_path(object.company_id, object.id),
      company: api_v1_company_path(object.company_id),
      products: api_v1_company_brand_products_path(object.company_id, object.id)
    }
  end

end
```

But this is a no go in the new version. What's the best way of resolving this so that I can keep my links in my serializer?

Edit:
For now I'm doing the following but would love to hear if there's a more idiomatic way.

```
class BaseSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
```

Comment: i think you best answered it

Answer (score 7):

If you add this to your `ApplicationController` or even probably to the controller generating the response:

`serialization_scope :view_context`

You can then use the `view_context` in the serialiser to access the URL helpers (or any view methods really).

Example: `view_context.api_v1_company_brand_path(object.company_id, object.id)`

I thought this was probably cleaner than including all those URL helpers etc... into the serialiser class.

Answer (score 1):

including the library which had been excluded (as you had done) would most definitely be the shortest route (outside of revising the gem itself, in terms of idiomacy)