# Active Model Serializers: Unable to acces user_url, can access user_path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, active-model-serializers

I've been battling with this JSON serialisation for about a week and a half now.
Whatever SO / Other site solution I try, I can never get the Fully Qualified URL (indepent of where the server runs). My ideal solution would be the one that would return http://localhost:3000/user/X if I ran it on my work pc, and https://host.name.organization.com/user/X on the production server. It has to be indepent of whatever system I run the server on. And because this rails host is behind a NGINX reverse proxy it would be great if it would just read from the Host Header.

As you can see in the code, the relative path (to the host) is defined and works perfectly, yet never the url. Other solutions ended up with a Rails error saying I need to statically define (basically hardcode) the url the server is running on.

Serializer

```
class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

  attributes :id, :email, :firstname, :lastname, :birthdate, :created_at, :updated_at

  attribute :uri do
    {user_path: user_path(object)}
  end

  #Latest addition, no visual result, yet no errors either.
  link(:self) { user_url(object) }
end
```

Current JSON Response

```
{
  "id": 37,
  "email": "test3@test.coma",
  "firstname": "Test",
  "lastname": "Test",
  "birthdate": "2017-03-13",
  "created_at": "2017-03-13T00:00:22.982Z",
  "updated_at": "2017-03-13T00:00:23.467Z",
  "uri": {
  "user_path": "/user/37"
  }
}
```

What it should be (if ran locally)

```
{
  Same as above
  "uri": {
     "user_path":"user/37",
     "user_url":"http://localhost:3000/user/37"
   }
}
```

If this is somehow a bug/missing feature in the gem, i'm willing to take it over to the [Github repo](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following line to your ApplicationController:

`serialization_scope :view_context`

Then in your serializer, you should be able to access it using the following example:

`view_context.user_url(object.id)`

Source: [Url Helpers in ActiveModelSerializer 0.10.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32768046/url-helpers-in-activemodelserializer-0-10-0)